# get_browser function is not working properly for me..

Tags: php

I have requirement to get full info of Browser ..Here is my code and output i am getting.

```
$user_agent =  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = get_browser($user_agent, true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($browser);echo "</pre>";
```

OUTPUT WHAT I AM GETTING AND WHICH IS NOT DESIRED IS

```
Array
(
   [browser_name_regex] => ^.*$
   [browser_name_pattern] => *
   [browser] => Default Browser
   [css] => 0
   [frames] => 
   [iframes] => 
   [tables] => 1
   [cookies] => 
   [backgroundsounds] => 
   [vbscript] => 
   [javascript] => 
   [javaapplets] => 
   [activexcontrols] => 
   [cdf] => 
   [aol] => 
   [beta] => 
   [win16] => 
   [crawler] => 
   [stripper] => 
   [wap] => 
   [netclr] => 
)
```

can anyone tell me where i am lacking to get desired output

Comment: don't you run it by chance in Command Line Interface? do echo($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); and publish the result here

Answer (score 2):

From [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

> #### Note:
>
> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in
>   php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on
>   your system.
>
> browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find an up-to-date
>   [php_browscap.ini file here](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp).
>
> While browscap.ini contains information on many browsers, it relies on
>   user updates to keep the database current. The format of the file is
>   fairly self-explanatory.

You will get this result if you have either not configured this, or if your configuration does not include the browser you're using. It's been years since I used this, but if I recall correctly you just need to download the file and include it in the same directory as your PHP file for this to work.